# Description Resource Path Location Type The constructor SQLiteAdapter(new BroadcastReceiver(){}) is undefined

Tags: android, sqlite

I am receiving an error "Description Resource   Path    Location Type The constructor SQLiteAdapter(new BroadcastReceiver(){}) is undefined" in my SMSReceiverActivity class.

The line with error is `mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);`

Here's the complete code:

```
package com.example.smsTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SMSReceiverActivity extends ListActivity {
    private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;

    private ArrayList<String> bodyarr = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt;

    private BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver;
    ListView listview;
    //ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_smsreceiver);

        listview=this.getListView();
        arrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SMSReceiverActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        bodyarr);

        listview.setAdapter(arrayAdpt);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN");
        mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String msg = intent.getStringExtra("get_msg");

                //Process the sms format and extract body &amp; phoneNumber
                msg = msg.replace("\n", "");
                String body = msg.substring(msg.lastIndexOf(":")+1, msg.length());
                String pNumber = msg.substring(0,msg.lastIndexOf(":"));

                bodyarr.add(body);

                arrayAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();

                /*
                 *  Create/Open a SQLite database
                 *  and fill with dummy content
                 *  and close it
                 */
                mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
                mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
                mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();

                mySQLiteAdapter.insert(body);

                mySQLiteAdapter.close();
            }
    };

    this.registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.unregisterReceiver(this.mIntentReceiver);
    }

}
```

Here's the code of my SQLiteAdapater:

```
package com.example.smsTest;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

public class SQLiteAdapter {

    public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
    public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "Content";

    //create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
    "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
    + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + KEY_CONTENT + " text not null);";

    private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    private Context context;

    public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
        context = c;
    }

    public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        sqLiteHelper.close();
    }

    public long insert(String content){

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    }

    public int deleteAll(){
        return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor queueAll(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
        null, null, null, null, null);

        return cursor;
    }

    public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

UPDATE:

I think SmsReceiver class in needed here:

Here it is:

```
package com.example.smsTest;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
       if (extras == null)
       return;

       Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
       for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
          SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
          String sender = SMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
          String body = SMessage.getMessageBody().toString();

         // A custom Intent that will used as another Broadcast
         Intent in = new Intent("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN").
         putExtra("get_msg", sender+":"+body);

         // To display a Toast whenever there is an SMS.
         Toast.makeText(context,body,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         //You can place your check conditions here(on the SMS or the sender)            
         //and then send another broadcast 
         context.sendBroadcast(in);

         /*Intent act = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
         act.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         act.putExtra("message", body);
         act.putExtra("sender", sender);
         context.startActivity(act);*/

        // This is used to abort the broadcast and can be used to silently
        // process incoming message and prevent it from further being 
        // broadcasted. Avoid this, as this is not the way to program an app.
        this.abortBroadcast();
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
```

In above statement, `this` refers to the instance of your anonymous `BroadcastReceiver` innerclass. In order to reference the encapsulating `Activity` as `Context` parameter, use the following:

```
mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(SMSReceiverActivity.this);
```